# I don't know why it is wrong when I import ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, built-in

I changed the definition of the builtin function len, then I tried to import the ctypes module.But I don't know why it occurs an error when I did that.Here is my code:

```
import builtins

def func(obj):
    print("Length: %d" % len(obj))
builtins.len = lambda obj: "Bad!!!"

import ctypes
```

Then here is the tracback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 772, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 491, in _code_to_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 42, in _w_long
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bad!!!'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
    import re
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 772, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 491, in _code_to_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 42, in _w_long
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bad!!!'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 772, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlibbootstrap_external>", line 491, in _code_to_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 42, in _w_long
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bad!!!'
```

This puzzles me a lot. Thanks very much if someone can help me!

Comment: Why are you puzzled?  Changing the functionality of a heavily-relied upon basic builtin then trying to use it (indirectly, through importing) as it was intended *should* cause an error, no?

Comment: Do you mean  the changed len function is excuted when I tried to import ctypes? @jedwards

Comment: The changed len fun is definitely called when you tried to import ctypes (see `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bad!!!'`).  I'm not sure why though, unless a version of ctypes has a dependency on the future package.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `len` function returns non integer string.

You just ran in the exact same behavior you could have with:

```
>>> int("I should know playing with builtins is always a bad thing")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lol'
```

Try to update your code like:

```
builtins.len = lambda obj: "123"
```

To see it.